# change output cell based on different cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a spreadsheet about my paylog.

I want to have a sum where it tells me how much still needs to be payed out based on if the box next to it is y or n (y=payed out, n=payed out, which means go into the sum box)

[image: view image here, it will help you understand it better]

After viewing that, this should be the result.

[image: What the output is meant to look like]

Comment: Based on the way you have it set up, there will be some circular dependencies.  D3 is a sum of C3:C200 and C3:C200 will have an if statement that is equal to D3 if B3 is n.  Can you provide more information to help clarify your need?

Comment: I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to track my work and a final price due to be payed out based of a y/n statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that info then I would change up a few different things to avoid the circular dependency.  For your total formula, I would use as SUMIF: `=SUMIF(B:B,"n",C:C)` That will only count the values in column c if column b is equal to "n".   Next I would use conditional formatting to change the font color to white for all values in column c when column b is equal to "y".  I've provided a demo sheet so you can view the results.  This will allow you to have values in column c which will remove the circular dependency issue.  Feel free to make a copy to be able to view the editable version.

Demo Sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KnbDQyt4hji4rhUjwWk9Fr8fLz0UTesx8QmViQnsvsY/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm sure there are many other ways to accomplish your goal but without more info...that is a direction I would go.